# How to avoid flow stopping in case of handler returns null?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have following configuration:

```
flow -> flow.handle(myHandler)
                .filter(p -> {
                    log.warn("FILTER IS INVOKED");
                    return p != null;
                }
```

In case if `myHandler#handle` returns null - filter is not invoked.

How could I achieve passing null value to the filter ?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with workaround: create wrapper over handler return type:

```
class Wrapper {
   Foo foo;
   ...
}
```

At this case I can do following:

```
flow -> flow.handle(myHandler)
                .filter(p -> {
                    log.warn("FILTER IS INVOKED");
                    return p.getFoo() != null;
                }
```